# How does the following variable allocation work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is probably a simple question, but can someone pls clarify the following javascript code?

```
// 'response' is the JSON data gotten from the backend:
....then(response => {
  this.myVar = response.data;
});

// 'myVar' is initialised here:
data: function() {
  return {
    myVar: null
  };
}
```

I can see how we declare a property 'data' that points to a function that returns an initialised variable 'myVar'.
I don't quite get how 'myVar' is set to the response value. I assume it is a JS technique? Can someone please explain this or provide me a link to such?

*** EDIT ***
From the responses, it seems I didn't supply enough info (sorry about that - I was assuming it be a simple JS issue). I extracted this code from a tutorial, and it works. The code excerpt is from a .vue file. So I supply the whole file here. The question is still the same.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button class="my-button" v-text="myVar.name" :type="type">My Button</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
      // The "api/vue" route calls a controller that supplies a JSON object with a single name=>value pair
      axios.post("api/vue", {}).then(response => {
      // ?? How exactly does myVar get allocated the JSON data?
      this.myVar = response.data;
    });
  },

  // initiate the 'myVar' variable 
  data: function() {
    return {
        // ?? this object is delared here and somehow accessible to the whole file?
      myVar: null
    };
  },

};
</script>
```

Comment: What is `test`?

Comment: @adiga Sorry - forgot to change the text after renaming 'test' to 'myVar' in the code - updated the question.

Comment: Is this a [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) or [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) app?

Comment: this is from a vue app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this whole code makes a Vue Component. In a Vue Component, initial `data` should be a function, which will be invoked when component created. the object that returned by `data()` is the initial data for the component, and it's observable(`observable` means, if you change it, something other will be changed also). the techniche of javascript used here is `Object.defineProperty` : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

base on your code, it says you have a initial data named 'myVar', if you change the value of 'myVar', the dom which bound with 'myVar' will change automatically. in your code, it's the text of the `button`.

**mounted**

this is a life-cycle hook, it will be invoked after the component mounted into the dom.

you called an AJAX at here, then you used **arrow function** to deal with the result of AJAX. `arrow function` means it's `this` will not change (here , `this` equals the Vue Component).

we already have a initial data 'myVar' on this component, now we change it:

```
this.myVar = response.data;
```

because it's observable/reactive, the text of the `button` in your template will be changed.

by the way, your initial `myVar` is null, so your initial text `myVar.name` will cause an error

Comment: Thanks for that great explanation - And for the link as well. Now I know where to look :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// 'response' is the JSON data gotten from the backend:
....then(response => {
    this.myVar = response.data;
});
```

In this first method, you are fetching data from a server, and assigning it this.myVar (not myVar). so it's local to the component, however...
In the code below, whenever you call data(), you are returning an object with a property myVar encapsulated in it. it is not the same as this.myVar.

```
// 'myVar' is initialised here:
data: function() {
   return {
      myVar: null
   };
}
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but these variables are unrelated. And maybe the naming needs some work too, so it's easier for us to see what the purpose of this code is. Either way, if this.myVar is a variable owned by your component, the object returned from the data() method will not have any effect on it, since it's structure is different. the myVar in the Object you are returning in data is a new variable, local to that object.